# Change reStructuredText format in PyCharm for auto-generated comments

Tags: python, pycharm, restructuredtext, type-hinting, docstring

The documentation from JetBrains says, that there are two formats for creating reStructuredText [comments with type-hinting](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/using-docstrings-to-specify-types.html):

```
:param param_type param_name: parameter description (type description is on the same line as the parameter description).
:type param_name: param_type (type description is on a separate line)
```

There used to be a way, how you could select one or the other way how comments were generated, but I can't find that setting in PyCharm 2017.1.2 anymore. Any ideas, where this setting went?

I want to have type description `param_type` in the same line, but the standard way puts it in the next line.

Comment: Did a find a way to put the type and the parameter on the same line? I'm looking for it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in Settings -> Tools -> Python Integrated Tools -> Docstrings -> Docstring format.

[image]

If I understand correctly the format you're after is the NumPy one.

Also, if you're using Python>=3.5, you may already know about type hints in variables and function parameters, which looks super tidy and save you space in the docstring: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

And sphinx supports them with one of:

- https://github.com/agronholm/sphinx-autodoc-typehints
- https://github.com/nicolashainaux/sphinx-autodoc-annotation

Comment: that doesn't seem what the OP asked, he asked of this type of format

":param var_name: text description

:type var_name: int"